# How can I see what triggered a ResizeObserverCallback?

Tags: javascript, resize-observer

I'm running into a recursive loop with a ResizeObserver, where *something* inside the observed container is changing the size of the container on re-render, which causes the ResizeObserver to re-trigger.

In this specific case, there are several items I suspect may be causing this, but haven't been able to pinpoint what causes it. Using the DevTools debugger, I'm able to see the ResizeObserver is triggered, but the Stack trace is empty.

There's a good chance it's caused by Javascript, but an equally good chance it's caused by some part of the css layout, which would not be stack trace-able.

Is there some way to see *why* the ResizeObserver is called?

The callback includes the target, but the target is the *observed* object, not the originally changed object. A minimal reproduction can be found here- https://jsfiddle.net/jamessw/5czoyws6/44/

```html
  <div id="observed">
    <div id="changed">
      This is short text that will get long
    </div>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div id="output">
    Entry target id:
  </div>
  <button id="changeButton">
    Change
  </button>
```

```js
const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    const output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML += entry.target.id + ' ';
  }
});
const element = document.getElementById('observed')
resizeObserver.observe(element);

const button = document.getElementById('changeButton');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const changed = document.getElementById('changed');
  changed.innerHTML += ' foo'
})
```

```css
#observed{
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Although it would be hard, but you can do it this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/71325034/9626938

Comment: I can't see any loop happening when trying your "minimal reproduction", nor anything that could cause one. What browser are you experiencing it on? (And no, there is no "source" for the resize observation)

Comment: @Kaiido Correct- the minimal reproduction is demonstrating that the target is the observed element. The loop is what inspired this question, but not the question itself. Since there doesn't appear to be a source, if you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!